# Http 1.1 pipelining support

Tags: http, web, pipelining

I enabled http pipelining support in google chrome and observerd some problems in how data is received even when using big sites like amazon.com. What is the current support for pipelining from major servers ? I wonder if issues can be caused also because of our transparent proxy (microsoft TMG) although http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc302548.aspx mentions that

"*ISA Server does not implement pipelining. Client request pipelining is supported, allowing a client to make multiple requests without waiting for each response. However, pipelining when sending requests to the Web server is not supported.*"  I think this should not cause data to be received wrongfully from the pipeline aware web server.

Comment: Well. Try without the proxy and compare the results.

Comment: @JulianReschke I currently can't without proxy.it's on the gateway machine

Comment: After trying also in places where I don't (personally) use any kind of proxy I can confirm that seems to be other failing points (proxies/servers or others) that could cause problems/retransmissions when using pipelining